# Ошибка expected unqualified-id before 'else'|

Tags: c++

Не работает код. Хотя должен. В чём проблема?

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;
#include <Windows.h>;
//namespace std;
//using std;
int main(){;

std::string pass;

std::cout<<"Write password";
std::cin >> pass;
if(pass != "passwordforc"){
    std::cout<<"Acess Denied"<<std::endl;
exit(0);}}
else{
    std::cout<<"Acess allowed";
    system("OXI_Joiner.exe");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Давайте всего лишь отформатируем ваш код...

```
int main()
{ 
    ;
    std::string pass;

    std::cout<<"Write password";
    std::cin >> pass;
    if(pass != "passwordforc")
    {
        std::cout<<"Acess Denied"<<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"Acess allowed";
    system("OXI_Joiner.exe");
}
```

Теперь вы сами видите проблему, правда?

Аккуратность - это не потому что мамка заругает, а потому что без нее возникают вот такие вот вопросы с очевидными ответами.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не надо убирать эту точку с запятой - из песни... в смысле, кода слово не выкинешь :)